# Count an unpredictable number of cells and then insert rows under specific rows depending on the result of the count

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a VBA code that achieves the following in the next database:

[image: First stage]

1. I want to count the number of cells from G1 to the right until the cells are empty. In this case, I'd have 10 cells, from G1 to P1. The number of cells is unpredictable. I'm having problems with that since I'm new to VBA, and that isn't even the hard part.
2. Then I want to divide the count by 2. And then insert as many rows under the rows 2,3,4,5... etc, aka under every row that is not empty as the value. In this case, since the count was 10, the code would insert five rows under row 2, five rows under row 3... It will always be an even number, that's not a problem.
3. Then I'd have to copy and paste the values in G2 and H2 into E3 and F3. And then I'd insert the values from I2 and J2 into E4 and F4, and so on until that row is finished, then move onto row 2 (in the second picture it would be row 8). Maybe it would be better to count the number of used cells and insert rows accordingly row by row? Then the code would be easier, I wonder.

It would end up looking something like this, although in the "Final stage picture" I have only done the first row.

Thanks, I hope I was clear enough.

[image: Final Stage]

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having which is preventing you from doing this?  What error(s) are you getting with your code? If you have no code, then the best approach is to try writing what you want, and post back here with the relevant lines, along with a description of what's not working, with any error messages you get, etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to write a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Although what you want is clear, SO is not a free code writing service. You are required to provide code you had tried and explain what and where you're having problems. Please update your post.